# JPA QueryDSL Count Aggregation By Days

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have this Sql Query. Which returns number of events generated per day.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, "%y-%m-%d") AS date , COUNT(*) 
FROM `Event` 
WHERE `active`=1 
GROUP BY date
```

Output

```
 |   date   |   Count   |
 ------------------------
 | 14-09-29 |     1     |
 | 14-11-02 |     1     |
 | 14-11-03 |     3     | 
     ...         ...
```

I want to do this query on JPA QueryDSL but I don't know how to do it because I haven't find the way to do `DATE_FORMAT('timestamp', "%y-%m-%d") AS date`

Is it possible to do this query on JPA QueryDSL or it can't be done by limitations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solve it with this Query. Also I've added date range filter.

```
 QEvent qEvent = QEvent.event;

 JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

 return query.from(qEvent)
                 .where(qEvent.active.eq(true)
                    .and(qEvent.sensorId.equalsIgnoreCase(sensorId)
                    .and(qEvent.timestamp.after(rangeStart)
                    .and(qEvent.timestamp.before(rangeEnd)))))
             .groupBy(qEvent.timestamp.dayOfYear())
             .list(new QTuple(qEvent.timestamp, Wildcard.count));
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@Formula annotation](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation) to add the calculated column to your entity and then use the calculated column in QueryDSL call.

```
public class MyEntity {
...
  @Formula('DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, "%y-%m-%d")')
  String myDatStr;
...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in this case. Finally, I 've found a query that does what I need. Thank you anyway :D

Comment: This solution may not be complete JPA, but it was a viable only way to use some expressions with dates in JPAQuerys. In my case, I wanted the difference between months of two dates. I used it that way.

`@Formula("ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(DATE_B, 'MONTH'), TRUNC(DATA_A, 'MONTH')),0)")
  String myDatStr;`